# Can we develope Hybrid project with ionic-v1 in visual studio 2017

Tags: ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

Can we develope Hybrid project with ionic-v1 in visual studio 2017? Can we develope only Ionic 2 application in Visual Studio? Please help me to come out of this confusion!

Comment: you need to install ionic cli and cordova thru command prompt after that you can write code even in notepad..no need of visual studio or any other ide

Comment: can I know the version of VS you are using?

Comment: I am using VS 2015 .